# posting contact form to email using php not working

Tags: php, forms, email

I have created a 'coming soon' landing page for my new website. Until the website design and development has been completed I just want to be able to collect interested parties email addresses - which should just submit to directly to my email. I have written the below code, however I am not receiving any emails to my address during testing:

HTML:

```
form method="post" name="myemailform" action="emailform.php">
<div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email address..." name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to hit submit";
}
$visitor_email = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$email_from = $_POST['emailAddress'];

// Validate FIRST
if(empty($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Email address is required";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "New Form";
$email_body = "You have received a new notifcation from $visitor_email.\n".

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n"

// SEND EMAIL
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

This is my first attempt at server-side scripting. Can you see anything incorrect in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional statement

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

is looking for a **named** submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

which should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

- Having [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would have signaled an `Undefined index` error.

Also you seem to be missing a `<` for `form method="post"` if that is your actual code.

You're also missing a semi-colon in `$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n"`

which should read as `$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";`

*Plus,*

```
$email_body = "You have received a new notifcation from $visitor_email.\n".
```

remove the dot at the end and replace with a semi-colon

```
$email_body = "You have received a new notifcation from $visitor_email.\n";
```

and use error reporting

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

being

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

placed just before your opening `<?php` tag, which will signal any errors if found in code.

---

Sidenote:

This `name="myemailform"` you don't need that.

Comment: @user3445112 You're welcome. You will need to make the appropriate changes to it and that's something I don't deal with, since I don't have a Webserver on my own machine, I've always had a hosted service. Try it on a hosted site if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the test from your local machine or from the hosting server? 
The requirements of sending emails can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the php.ini? You need a working email system installed in your server or access to the php.ini to configure the SMTP parameters. What OS are you running?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have SMTP server setup on your machine to send mails.